# Not able to open iReport Designer in mac

Tags: macos, ireport

I'm new to Jasper reports and Mac. I have downloaded iReport-5.6.0.dmg. It got saved in downloads. Later I moved to applications. The .dmg didnt install and when I just open the .dmg and right click to open for Jaspersoft report designer, it didnt open.

I just saw some questions, but nothing helped.

I'm using mac os Sierra 10.12.2

My java version is

```
Alis-MacBook-Air:~ Shah$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
Alis-MacBook-Air:~ Shah$
```

### JDK location

```
Alis-MacBook-Air:~ Shah$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8.0_101, x86_64:  "Java SE 8"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
1.7.0_79, x86_64:   "Java SE 7"  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
```

### iReport.conf

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/5.6.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application  Support/${APPNAME}/5.6.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999 "
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home"

# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon  on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup JDK 1.7s as JAVA_HOME otherwise you'll see like this error
**"The current path is: C: \ Java \ jdk1.8.0The current path is: C: \ Java \ jdk1.8.0Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize = 512m; support was removed in 8.0"** and you can setup jaspersoft studio community its working.

Comment: now Jaspersoft studio is  already working. I'm using as 1.8 JDK.

Comment: Yes,i know it is working correctly,but unfortunately iReport doesn't support 1.8 JDK

Comment: Correct.. Do you know how to pass a POJO object as Datasource in Java?

Comment: i know but this is different question if you close this question then i can answer other question

Comment: Sure. Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910433/pass-pojo-object-to-jrbean-to-generate-jasper-report

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the JDK version.

If the JDK version is 1.8, Jasperstudio has to be installed. It worked fine.